# An Amazon EC2 "Micro" (smallest) linux instance can reliably serve a dynamic website to how many users?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, amazon-ec2, hosting, lighttpd

How "large" of a website can one reliably host on Amazon EC2's micro instance?

Running apache, nginx, lighty, I don't care.

Just curious how far that $5.20/month would get you and why I should or should not go this route.

Comment: $5.20/month? I thought it is $0.025 per hour * 730 hours in a month = $18.25

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is so dependant on how resource heavy the site is, not possible to give an generic answer to such an unspecified question. Kind of like; *how much water can the sun evaporate?*

*Here's what I would do:*
Setup nginx + php-fpm, setup a phpinfo(); .php page, cache it with fastcgi_cache and then try it with [apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), or even [loadimpact.com](http://www.loadimpact.com). Don't forget to post your results! :-)

Please note that there are information that suggests that the [AWS EC2 Micro Instance's CPU time frequently is stolen](http://gregsramblings.com/2011/02/07/amazon-ec2-micro-instance-cpu-steal/) (I think written by a SF member), [it does NOT deliver a consistent CPU resource](http://www.scriptkiddie.org/blog/2011/03/24/amazon-ec2-micro-instances-really-really-suck/), [as stated on AWS site](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).

Comment: Indeed, my experience with micro is that the processing-performance usually fluctuate quite heavily.